# Jquery sortable, but from left <-> right and not up <-> down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have looked around and i wast able to find a way so sort div elements from left to right and right to left.

What i am doing, is i am creating a website where a user can move navigation pane either to the right or do the left of the body pane.

I have looked at http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/ and it almost does what i need, although it sorts from top to bottom and reversal. Is there anything possible to do the same only from left to right and in reversal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery UI sortable should do just fine.

Let's say your divs have a class "foobar". Just give them a width and float them:

```
div.foobar {
  width:100px;
  float:left;
  margin-right:5px;
}
```

Comment: I did a quick draft
    <html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <style>
  div.foobar {
   width:100px;
   float:left;
   margin-right:5px;
 }

  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
   $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
   $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  });
  </script>
<body>
 <div id="sortable">
<div class='foobar'>1</div>
<div class='foobar'>2</div>


 </div>
</div>
</head>
</body>
`

Comment: Run into a small issue. Is the way to change css based on where certain div is located. When both of them are floating left, when i move the menu to right, there is a small empty space on the right.